# Avoid nested loops

Tags: postgresql-performance

I've the following query:

```
Select GAD.OWNREF, GAD.ADCODE, GAD.CORNAM, GAD.NOMCUR1, GAD.OPNCUR1, ​​
GAD.OPNAMT1, GAD.EXPDAT, GAD.CONFLG, GAD.GACTYP, GAD.OWNNAM, GAD.GACRUL, ​​
GAD.CORREF, GAD.GACFRM, GAD.CTYCOD, GAD.BENADR, GAD.ADDIVI, GAD.ADAREA, ​​
GAD.ADUNIT, GAD.ADDPRT, GAD.ADCOST, GAD.UTLCUR1, GAD.UTLAMT1, GAD.OPNDAT, ​​
GAD.FRODAT, GAD.EXPFLG, GAD.LIADAT, GAD.AVLGRP, GAD.CREUSR, GAD.CONFLG, ​​
GAD.AMENBR, GAD.GACCON, GAD.FORADR, GAD.CLSDAT, GAD.COREXT, GAD.INR, ​​
gad.beninr, gad.owninr, gad.lsbinr
From GAD GAD
where ( GAD.TIDEXTKEY  in ​​( N'AEAPG') and
        GAD.GRP in ( select distinct TID.GRP
                    from UCL UCL, TID TID 
                    ​​where GAD.TIDEXTKEY  in ​​( N'AEAPG' ) ) and
        GAD.ETGEXTKEY  in ( N'HE' ) ) and
 GAD.ADCODE = GAD.ADCODE and ​​
 GAD.ADDIVI = GAD.ADDIVI and
 GAD.ADAREA = GAD.ADAREA and
 GAD.ADUNIT = ​​GAD.ADUNIT and
 GAD.ADDPRT = GAD.ADDPRT and
 GAD.CREUSR = GAD.CREUSR and ​​
 GAD.COREXT = GAD.COREXT and
 GAD.GACTYP = GAD.GACTYP and
 GAD.CTYCOD = ​​GAD.CTYCOD and
 GAD.GACCON <> N'3' and
 trim(OWNREF) is not NULL
```

The plan is using nested loops and running take a lot of time (33 Min!)

There Is a way to write it In a better way , I know that there is a option to set nested_loops to off but this will bot hurt another query.
One last question is there is a way to use parallel when access to the big table gad?
Thank you in advance.

Comment: What's the purpose of all the comparisons of the same columns, e.g. `GAD.ADCODE = GAD.ADCODE`?  Note that `distinct` in the sub-query used for an IN condition is useless (but removing it won't make a substantial difference in perormance). Additionally your sub-query does not join the tables `ucl` and `tid` properly resulting a cross join. The WHERE clause of the subquery seems pretty useless as well as it doesn't restrict the result of that cross join at all. `trim(OWNREF) is not NULL` can be replaced with `ownref is not null`  (trim won't magically turn a value that's not null into NULL)

Answer (score 0):

Do not be afraid to format your queries. The "ladder" does wonders to understanding the query.

Huge error in subselect:

```
select distinct TID.GRP
from UCL UCL, TID TID 
​​where GAD.TIDEXTKEY  in ​​( N'AEAPG' )
```

What is the point of including here table UCL? It multiply number of rows in TID, which later reduced by `distinct` - a lot of useless work. Fix it, and you will see a lot of performance improvement.

Another problem with the subquery - it is selecting distinct GRP from table TID, but it has some additional condition `​​where GAD.TIDEXTKEY  in ​​( N'AEAPG' )`. What for??? GAD is a table outside the subquery and it this condition is already exist.

A lot of useless conditions where a field is compared to itself. Not much of performance issue but clatter query a lot and makes it difficult to read.

What is the point of `GAD.TIDEXTKEY  in ​​( N'AEAPG')`? If it is just one value for to be checked, use `=`: `GAD.TIDEXTKEY = N'AEAPG'`

No need to give alias to the table if the alias is the same as table name.

If you have just one table in the query, you do not need to specify it when addressing columns.